# Is there a & logical operator in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if there is a "&" logical operator in Javascript.  I tried running 1 & 0 and 1 && 0 in Firebug(Firefox) and it returned a 0 for both.

Someone told me that C# accepts both & and double &&, double being more efficient as it will exit the comparison loop as soon as a false is encountered, but I was not able to find any info for Javascript on that.

Any ideas?

Comment: And how about trying `1 && 1`, which would actually show you what's going on...?

Comment: 1 && 1 returns 1 and 1 & 1 returns 1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535328/what-do-these-javascript-bitwise-operators-do

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No.  `&` is a [bitwise AND](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) operator.  `&&` is the only logical AND operator in Javascript.

Comment: It's *like* a logical "AND" operator, but unlike other languages it does not produce a boolean result value unless its operands are boolean.

Answer (score 5):

The `&&` operator returns `0` for the expression `1 && 0` because its semantics are different than those of the same operator (well, symbolically the same) in other C-like languages.

In Javascript, the `&&` operator *does* coerce its operands to boolean values, but *only* for the purposes of evaluation. The result of an expression of the form

```
e1 && e2 && e3 ...
```

is the **actual** value of the first subexpression *`en`* whose coerced boolean value is `false`. If they're all `true` when coerced to boolean, then the result is the **actual** value of the last *`en`*. Similarly, the `||` operator interprets an expression like this:

```
e1 || e2 || e3 ...
```

by returning the **actual** value of the first *`en`* whose coerced boolean value is `true`. If they're all false, then the value is the **actual** value of the last one.

Implicit in those descriptions is the fact that both `&&` and `||` stop evaluating the subexpressions as soon as their conditions for completion are met.

Answer (score 3):

1 & 0 is 0.

It's a bitwise operator, not a logical operator.

&& means a logical AND of the left and right operators.  This means it will return a boolean true value only if both the left and right operators resolve to boolean true.

& means a bitwise AND of the left and right operators.  This means the bits of each operand will be compared and the result will be the ANDed value, not a boolean.  If you do `101 & 100` the return value is `100`.  If you do `1 & 0`, the return value is `0`.

You've been mislead about the meaning of the two operators if someone told you the difference was just in efficiency.  They have very different uses.

Comment: That's not exactly right about `&&`.  The expression `"hello" && 0` returns `0`, not `false`, and the expression `"hello" && "world"` returns "world", not `true`.

Comment: I understand JavaScript behaves different than what I described, but I was more concerned with the distinction between logical and bitwise AND (and how they behaves in "most" languages).

Comment: Right on both accounts.  In any case, it may be worth noting that JavaScript's `&&` and `||` operators return *truthy/fasley* values, not necessarily booleans.  They also act like C#'s coalesce operator `??` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx `&&` will return the first *falsey* value or the last *truthy* value; `||` will return the first *truthy* value.

Answer (score 2):

Your friend is wrong about C#.

C# does not mix logical and bitwise operators, so you cannot use & where && is needed or vice versa.

1 & 0 returns 0

true && false returns false

So if you're writing an if statement, which expects a boolean, you have to use &&. And if you're doing bit-wise arithmetic, then you need &.

Comment: Interesting.  Java does allow boolean operations with `&` and `|`, and in that context they exist explicitly to avoid short-circuiting.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Javascript has both. http://www.eecs.umich.edu/~bartlett/jsops.html

Exactly as is true in C#, the double && version can stop as soon as it encounters a false, and the single & version may not.

Answer (score 1):

You can check this for bitwise in javascript:

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_bitwise.asp

& is Sets each bit to 1 if both bits are 1

Examples:
5 & 1   = 1

0101 & 0001 = 0001

Answer (score 0):

&& is the logical operator in Javascript. 1 && 0 should return false so it is performing correctly.

Comment: Not that. I was asking about a single & operator.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has the bitwise (&) and boolean (&&) operators. The reason && returns a 0 on 1 && 0 is because 0 would indicate false and so 1 (true) && 0 (false) returns a false as both operators must evaluate to true to return a true

Comment: But why return "0" instead of "false" ?

Comment: This is right but it doesn't return `false`, it returns the actual value of the first expression that, when coerced to boolean, is `false`.

Comment: @James Curran because `&&` and `||` in Javascript are **different** than the similar operators in C and Java etc.  They do not return a boolean result unless working with boolean subexpressions.