# Javascript boolean console.log(true & true); why 1?

Tags: javascript

```
console.log(true & true);
```

I am a novice developer who is learning JavaScript.
I wonder why 1 is printed out if I write the code above.

Comment: If you want to "true" result. Try && instead of &. Javascript operators are little bit strange :)

Comment: I am too curious about this. Best I can find is this docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_AND

Comment: @cbalakus Actually, almost every C-like languages use these operators the same way as JS does...

Comment: [Is there a & logical operator in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3374811)

Answer (score 3):

In JavaScript, `true` is evaluated to `1`.

So, in short:

```js
console.log(true & true)
```

is equal to:

```js
console.log(1 & 1)
```

The output of bitwise `AND` is 1 if the corresponding bits of two operands is 1. If either bit of an operand is 0, the result of corresponding bit is evaluated to 0. It's boolean logic.

Read more about boolean logic [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_AND).

Answer (score 0):

**&** is a bit operator and work on 32 bits numbers. Any numeric operand in the operation is converted into a 32 bit number. Any non-numeric operand is similarly converted to a number before the operation. The result is converted back to a JavaScript *number*.

**&&** is a logical operator and will return *true* or *false*

```js
console.log(true & true);
console.log(true && true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Bit operators work on 32 bits numbers. Any numeric operand in the operation is converted into a 32 bit number. The result is converted back to a JavaScript number. In your case:

> `true = 1 => 0001`
> Thats why
> `0001 & 0001 = 0001 => 1`

[image: Bit operators work on 32 bits numbers. Any numeric operand in the operation is converted into a 32 bit number. The result is converted back to a JavaScript number.]

ref: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_operators.asp