# Trying to understand the leap year test - 'year & 3' 'year & 15'

Tags: javascript, leap-year

I am trying to understand the code used to determine if a year is a leap year, I am stuck with this part

```
(year & 3 || !(year % 25) && year & 15 ? 28 : 29)
```

I don't get what `year & 3` or `year & 15` means. I know in some programming languages the ampersand sign is used for concetanation, I don't think that is the case here.

I know what `&&` means, just not sure what a single ampersand on it own means.

I have read a bit about the leap year test regarding numbers being divisible by 4,100 and 400. But I can't find anything abohut `& 3` and `& 15`.

Comment: It's bitwise AND. It's an obfuscated way to test for multiples of 4 and 16.

Comment: [Is there a & logical operator in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3374811) | [What do these JavaScript bitwise operators do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4535328) | [What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9549780)

Comment: This code seems to be deliberately intended to be confusing, or maybe it's Code Golf so they're going for the shortest formula.

Comment: Shouldn't these be answers? I think the question is fully answered by these comments.

Comment: Barmar this the whole test -    daysPerMonth = month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11 ? 30
        : (month == 2 ? (year & 3 || !(year % 25) && year & 15 ? 28 : 29) : 31);

Comment: 00000000011 - 3
 11111010000 - 2000

So in the year 2000 would 'year & 3' give you 00000000000?